# Не могу добавить элемент в словарь python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, dict

А почему я не могу написать `d[Parent] += d1`? `Parent` является строкой, а `d1` - словарем. В принципе позволяет только строку добавить. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать? Выдает ошибку:

> TypeError: must be str, not dict

Раньше получалось по ключу добавлять целые списки.
Мне нужно, чтобы по одному значению было доступно несколько словарей:

```
#Теперь у нас есть ребенок и родитель. Это строки
d1 = {Children : "misha567889"}
print(d1)
d[Parent] += d1
```

Comment: убери += на равно или же делай массив,  а потом append, если значений много

Comment: То есть я не могу поставить значением словарь?

Comment: Можете: `d[Parent] = d1`

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dict1 = {1 : 123}
parent = 2
dict1.get(parent) # None - его не сущетсвует
# None + dict = TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'dict'
dict2 = {3 : 333}
dict1[parent] = dict2

print(dict1.get(parent)) # {3: 333}

dict1[parent] += {} # TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'dict' and 'dict'

dict3 = {4 : 444}

dict1[parent] = []
dict1[parent].append(dict2)
dict1[parent].append(dict3)

print(dict1[parent]) # [{3: 333}, {4: 444}]
```

Значение может содержать все что угодно, как и переменная

А ключ уже не все

`Python Dictionaries Require Hashable Keys`

То есть tuple уже нельзя

Comment: `tuple` как-раз может быть ключём словаря - кортежи в питоне `immutable` и поэтому `hashable`